# how to format a shell command line from a list of arguments in python

Tags: python, shell, command-line, formatting, command-line-arguments

I have a list of arguments, e.g. `["hello", "bobbity bob", "bye"]`. How would I format these so they would be passed appropriately to a shell?

**Wrong**:

```
>>> " ".join(args)
hello bobbity bob bye
```

**Correct**:

```
>>> magic(args)
hello "bobbity bob" bye
```

Comment: Do you need to handle cases when some arguments may contain quotes `"`'s or backslashes? `\ `'s?.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: yeah.. i basically want exactly how it would be passed by `popen`, but as a command line

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the undocumented but long-stable (at least [since Oct 2004](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/subprocess.py?revision=37587&view=markup)) `subprocess.list2cmdline`:

```
In [26]: import subprocess
In [34]: args=["hello", "bobbity bob", "bye"]

In [36]: subprocess.list2cmdline(args)
Out[36]: 'hello "bobbity bob" bye'
```

Comment: ah perfect.. exactly what i wanted. i wonder why it's not documented

Answer (score 1):

The easier way to solve your problem is to add \"...\" whenever your text has at least two words.
So to do that :

```
# Update the list
for str in args:
  if len(str.split(" ")) > 2:
    # Update the element within the list by
    # Adding at the beginning and at the end \"

    ...

# Print args
" ".join(args)
```

Comment: Cases where this doesn't work:

    list_to_cmdline(['curl', 'http://site/page.html?x=1&y=2'])
    list_to_cmdline(['quotes', '"\''])
    list_to_cmdline(['echo', 'star', '*'])

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually sending the values to a shell script, `subprocess.popen` handles this for you:

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html?highlight=popen#subprocess.Popen

Otherwise, I believe you're down to string manipulation. `shlex.split` does the opposite of what you want, but there doesn't seem to be a reverse.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the old-school approach:

```
>>> args = ["hello", "bobbity bob", "bye"]
>>> s = ""
>>> for x in args:
...     s += "'" + x + "' "
...
>>> s = s[:-1]
>>> print s
'hello' 'bobbity bob' 'bye'
```

It doesn't matter if single-word arguments are quoted as well.

Comment: Works for those arguments, but can cause problems (including security issues) if the arguments can possibly contain single quotes.